# Selenium WebDriver Drop Down List Testing With Div tag in java

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, selenium-webdriver, test-automation-framework, functional

I am new to **automated testing** with Selenium Web Driver I am not able to work out how to test drop down lists without using the select command.

I tried using **xpath**, **select by id**, **class name**, **css selector**, but the drop down list does not open or select the child item in the list.

Please provide me with code samples for this.

My code :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("html body.modal-open.page-overflow div.modal-scrollable div#responsive.modal.hide.fade.modal-overflow.in div#update_data1.modal-body form#finv div#rootwizard3 div.tab-content div#tab1.tab-pane.no_padding.active div.form_row div.field div#dn_chzn.chzn-container.chzn-container-single a.chzn-single span")).submit();
            Select drpname = new  Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/form/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/a")));
            driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[4]/div/div[2]/form/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/div/div/a/span=1001 (2015-04-29 10:49:11)"));

    drpname.getOptions();
    drpname.getFirstSelectedOption();
    drpname.selectByIndex(1);
    drpname.selectByVisibleText("1000 (2015-04-29 10:47:45)");
    drpname.selectByValue("1000 (2015-04-29 10:47:45)");
```

---

The HTML I am trying to test is here:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjoe2.png]

---

Comment: Possibly part of your problem, but a css selector that long is prone to be very brittle.  If any element you're using is out of place then your desired element will not be able to be located.  Think about how you can locate your desired element while using as few other elements as possible as anchors.  For example, if there is no other element with the class "chzn-single" then you could use the css selector "a.chzn-single span"

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here because your `<select>` has `style="display: none;"`. In this case, I think you should click on the div first and try to Select option.

**Below is my code:**

```
WebElement divClick = driver.findElement("//div[@class='form_row']/div");
divClick.click();

WebElement dropdown = driver.findElement("//select[@id='dn']");
Select select = new Select(dropdown);
select.selectByVisibleText("your text here");
```

Try it first. Hope it helps for you. If there's any error, please let me know. 
When trying to find element, try using the `WebDriverWait` like :

```
dynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, second))
                 .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("your css here"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't appear to be a traditional select list. Based on a very similar jQuery dropdown I believe you will first want to click the below element

```
<div id="dn_chzn"....>
```

You can do this with the simple locater below

```
driver.findElement(By.id("dn_chzn")).click()
```

At this point the dropdown should be open. The list of options is actually nested in the element I list below, which unfortunately is not expanded in the screenshot.

```
<div class="chzn-drop"....>
```

Once more based on a similar jQuery plugin, an xpath query you could use I have listed below.

```
//div[@class='chzn-drop']//li[contains(text(),'1001 (2015-04-29 10:49:11)')]
```

Replace the dropdown selection text in the contains() portion of the query with the text of the element you would like to select.

Answer (score 0):

My product use AngularJS and Select2 jquery for the dropdown and it appears same as your case, hope my exeperience can help you

There are 2 ways to do

1. Execute JS to enable the dropdown, then select item as normal

   > driver.ExecuteScript($('elementLocator').attr('Style','display:block'))
2. Click on div first to enable something (as @scorpion mentioned)
   , then sendkeys to text field (in my case) or select from dropdown if the drop down is enabled now.

Answer (score 0):

Executing a javascript click on the option from the dropdown should work, because for a javascript click to work elementToClicked should be present on the dom (it does not matter if its display is none or not).

Snippet (java):

```
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click;", driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("optionFromDropdown")));
```

Comment: This would also work if the drop down doesn't and therefor isn't really testing user experience. A purely gui based approach would probably be more effective from a QA point of view.